# Static Variables in code

Tags: c++, time, static, int, keyword

After a bit of research I'm surprised to say I have not found a question like this anyway I'm just wondering why I can't assign a value to a static variable?

note I am not using any headers I'm just creating a class in one cpp file(I know not good practice) here is the error I get

```
main.cpp|17|error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'Rabbit::now'|
```

In Java this wouldn't be a problem

thanks

```
class Rabbit
{

 public:
     string name;
     string color;
     int age;
     bool friendly;
     int happiness;
     static time_t now = 4;
     const int currentID;
};
```

Comment: *"In Java this wouldn't be a problem"* - C++ has a different philosophy than Java

Comment: C++ is not Java. Just because they have a similar syntax doesn't mean that the languages themselves are similar.

Comment: Do note that this is allowed in C++17, *if* the variable is also marked as `inline`. Then no separate definition is needed as well.

Comment: I was equally surprised that "å gubevars för dumt fôlk" means nothing in Gaeilc even though it's a human language with very similar punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just wondering why I can't assign a value to a static variable?

You most certainly can assign any value you'd like to a static variable. You just do not assign it within the class definition itself.  The reason for this is that you cannot initialize a `static` variable more than once! If you were allowed to initialize it inside the class definition, that would be problematic.

> I am not using any headers I'm just creating a class in one cpp file (I know not good practice)

Right. Well if you were using headers you'd see why `static` variable initialization inside the class definition would be problematic. Each translation unit where the header is included would be trying to initialize the static variable, which cannot happen hence the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how you would do this in c++, then

```
//.h
class Rabbit
{
public:
    static int now;

};

//.cpp
int Rabbit::now = 4;
```